# Not respecting dependency order?

Tags: puppet

I have a couple Puppet modules which I've created which compile and install `x264`, which depends on `yasm`, a compiler.

The modules look like this:

```
class yasm {
    $install_dir = "/usr/local/yasm"

    include yasm::download, yasm::compile, yasm::install
}

class x264 {
    require yasm

    $install_dir = "/usr/local/x264"

    include x264::download, x264::compile, x264::install
}
```

Thus, when I declare a dependency on `x264` in my node, I expect that `yasm` will be downloaded, compiled, and installed before anything happens with `x264`.

However, this isn't what happens at all:

```
[default] Running provisioner: puppet...
Running Puppet with vagrant-precise64.pp...
stdin: is not a tty
warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
warning: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: precise64
info: Applying configuration version '1385018183'
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Download/File[x264-dir]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Download/Exec[x264-clone]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: Makefile:3: config.mak: No such file or directory
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: cat: config.h: No such file or directory
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: ./configure
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: Found no assembler
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: Minimum version is yasm-1.2.0
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: make: *** [config.mak] Error 1
err: /Stage[main]/X264::Compile/Exec[x264-compile]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: make returned 2 instead of one of [0] at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/x264/manifests/compile.pp:21
notice: /Stage[main]/X264::Install/Exec[x264-install]: Dependency Exec[x264-compile] has failures: true
warning: /Stage[main]/X264::Install/Exec[x264-install]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
notice: /Stage[main]/Yasm::Download/File[yasm-dir]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/Yasm::Download/Exec[yasm-download]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Yasm::Download/Exec[yasm-extract]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Yasm::Compile/Exec[yasm-configure]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Yasm::Compile/Exec[yasm-compile]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Yasm::Install/Exec[yasm-install]/returns: executed successfully
notice: Finished catalog run in 22.66 seconds
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

puppet apply --verbose --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' --color=false --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/vagrant-precise64.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

For whatever reason, my Puppet apply tries installing x264 *before* installing yasm, which is a *dependency* of x264. What am I doing wrong? How can I express that x264 completely depends on yasm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x264` depends directly on `yasm`, but `yasm` does not depend on anything.

The `include`s in `yasm` merely add it to the catalog, but do not provide any dependency structure for it.

One way to do it would be:

```
class yasm {
    $install_dir = "/usr/local/yasm"

    require yasm::download, yasm::compile, yasm::install
}

class x264 {
    require yasm

    $install_dir = "/usr/local/x264"

    Class['yasm'] -> class{ 'x264::download': }
    Class['yasm'] -> class{ 'x264::compile': }
    Class['yasm'] -> class{ 'x264::install': }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, even this doesn't seem to work for me. I had to `require yasm` in `x264::compile`. Why does a requirement in a dependency class mean more than a requirement at the top level of the module?

Comment: Whoops, my previous flawed suggestion was placing a dependency for the `x264`, but **not** for the classes it included, which have no dependencies themselves as well.

Therefore placing the `require` directly in the class that needs it (ie. `x264::compile`) actually works.

Comment: I changed my example to include adding dependencies for the `x264::` classes as well. Hopefully that works!